# Joi file validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, joi

I am trying to add a validation for images in my application using Joi. I use `react-hook-from` along with `joi`. My form looks as follows

```
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<AvatarForm>({
    resolver: joiResolver(AvatarSchema),
  });
```

where `AvatarSchema` and `AvatarForm` are defined as follows

```
export type AvatarForm = {
    avatar: File;
};

export const AvatarSchema = Joi.object<AvatarForm, true>({
    avatar: Joi.object({
      type: Joi.string().valid("image/png", "image/jpeg"),
      size: ...,
      ...
    }).unknown(true),
});
```

I'd like check the type and size of an image uploaded by a user. But whenever I upload an image, the image is indeed uploaded, I can render it using an `img` tag, then if I submit a form I got the following error

```
joi.ts:64 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at c (joi.ts:64:1)
    at async _executeSchema (createFormControl.ts:382:1)
    at async createFormControl.ts:1024:1
```

If I change the schema to

```
avatar: Joi.object().unknown(true),
```

Everything seems to work, form submit works correctly but I don't have any validation in that case. Also my submit function only logs the form data.